# How to get the maximum possible width of a div?

Tags: javascript, css, html, width

I need to know how one can get the maximum possible width of a div. Generally, a `<div>`'s width is limited by it's parent, meaning that it can not be larger than a certain amount. How that certain amount can be calculated?

I need this to calculate if the text inside the current `<div>` has overflown, (since the only way to detect a text overflow is to compare it's current width to its current clientWidth).

Thanks!

Comment: No it's not, a division can spread far and wide outside of it's containing elements. And why do you need to calculate it? If it's for scrollbars, there's a better and much easier way.

Comment: Somebody correct me if I'm wrong - my understanding is that a child can have a max width of `parent_width - parent_left_padding - parent_right_padding`, beyond which scrollbars will appear.

Comment: @Amarghosh: For a normal, default element, yes. But if you set the width of a division to 150% (for example) it will spread past the parent element out on its own. I had that problem when I was trying to set the division width to 100% before, it kept adding the padding into the calculations and it was going past the edge of the parent element.

Comment: Block-level elements in the normal flow also spill beyond their containers if given negative margins.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple ways to do this, let's start with your div...

```
<div id='mr_cleaver'>
  <div id='beaver'>Blah</div>
</div>
```

...and then someJavascript:

```
//Method One: Find the width of the div's parent
var max_beaver_width = $('mr_cleaver').offsetWidth

//Method Two: Max out the div, find length, return to original size.
var beaver_width = $('beaver').offsetWidth;
$('beaver').style.width = "100%";
var max_beaver_width = $('beaver').offsetWidth;
$('beaver').style.width = beaver_width + 'px';

//Method Three: Check for overflow
$('beaver').scrollWidth > $('beaver').offsetWidth ? alert("Over") : alert("Within")
```

Comment: Thanks Steve!
Your suggestions were very helpful. Although none of them worked for me(probably I didn't explain my situation very well), but I could find a way to detect text overflow:


/* specifying the height of 'beaver'*/
var font_size= $('beaver').css("font-size");
font_size = parseInt(font_size.replace(/[a-z]*/gi,''));
var maxHeight = font_size + 4; // 4 is to make sure that the font fits in the maxHeight
/*now calculate current height*/
$('beaver').style.overflow-y:visible;
$('beaver').style.overflow-x:hidden;
if(elem.clientHeigth > maxHeight){
    //overflow has been occured
}

Comment: To clean up your suggestion for #2, it is much better performed as:
    var beaverContainer = $("#beaver")[0];
    var beaver_width = beaverContainer.style.width;
    beaverContainer.style.width = "100%";
    var max_beaver_width = beaverContainer.offsetWidth;

Comment: To clean up your suggestion for #2, it is much better performed as:
    
    var beaverContainer = $("#beaver")[0];
    var beaver_width = beaverContainer.style.width;
    beaverContainer.style.width = "100%";
    var max_beaver_width = beaverContainer.offsetWidth;
    beaverContainer.style.width = beaver_width;
    
    
This way your still allowing CSS to do its job unless width was implicity specified on the object, such as width: 25% in CSS and width: auto, without inline styles overtaking CSS rules. Setting a style property to null will remove the inline style.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Steve!

Your suggestions were very helpful. Although none of them worked for me(probably I didn't explain my situation very well), but using your hints, I could find a way to detect text overflow:

```
/* specifying the height of 'beaver'*/
var font_size= $('beaver').css("font-size");
font_size = parseInt(font_size.replace(/[a-z]*/gi,''));
var maxHeight = font_size + 4; // 4 is to make sure that the font fits in the maxHeight

/*now calculate current height*/
$('beaver').style.overflow-y:visible;
$('beaver').style.overflow-x:hidden;
var cuurentHeight = $('beaver').clientHeigth;

/* check whether overflow is occured*/
if(cuurentHeight > maxHeight){
    //overflow has been occured
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to be 100 % in width with no space between the edges, you can try to add this simpel CSS style to the div:

```
<style type="text/css">
  #FullWidthDiv {        // EDIT
    position: absolute; // If you use 'fixed' as position, then the div
    display: block;     // won't become smaller when the screen is at is smallest.
float: left;        // The fixed position is good when you for example want the
width: 100%;        // menu to stay in place.
background-color: #06F;
height: auto;
left: 0px;
top: 0px
}
</style>

<html>
<body>
<div id="FullWidthDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can append a div into parent element to measure it.

```js
var test = document.querySelector('#test');

var div = document.createElement('div');
div.style.width = '10000px';
test.appendChild(div);
var maxWidth = test.offsetWidth;
test.removeChild(div);
alert(maxWidth);
```

```css
#test {
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```